# Dataframe value not updating when iterating over rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to Pandas, and am trying to use it to analyse a large dataset. I have read everything I can find about it, but just can't get it to work. I am trying to update values in a dataframe whilst iterating over it row by row, but the values are not being updated in the dataframe.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for j in data_column:
        this_value = some_value
        print(this_value) # prints some_value
        df.loc[index].at[j] = this_value
        print(df.loc[index].at[j]) # prints 0 (not updated)
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output? Because `iterrows` is by default really slow and maybe exist some vectorized alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
df.at[index, j] = this_value
```

instead combination `loc` and `at`:

```
df.loc[index].at[j] = this_value
```

But `iterrows` is used only for some specific solutions, better is use some alternatives.

[Does iterrows have performance issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002)

Comment: I have already tried that, and I get the same result. Tried every version I could find! If there's nothing obviously wrong with the code I posted, then I wonder if there is another mistake somewhere else (I posted a very simplified, shortened version of my code). This is driving me crazy!

Just out of interest though, why would you choose df.at over df.loc? I don't completely understand the difference between what they do.

Comment: @mtomtom - Hard to know what is wrong, is necessary [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)